# Gradle issue - You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to generate a release version for my app I get the bellow error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Blockquote

```
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
```

How can I force *Android Studio Gradle plugin* to use `-dontwarn` option ?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the release build is using `Proguard`. You will need to add `Proguard` rules in `proguard-rules.pro` for some of the dependencies you are using. Most libraries provide the `Proguard` rules needed; look on their `README` page.

Comment: Most of my dependencies are remote libs ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you using gradle?

Comment: Local dependencies or not, you must add the '-dontwarn' option in your Proguard file to bypass that error.

Comment: Marius is correct. Regardless you still need to add the proguard rules. These rules are often provided by the creator of the libs.

Answer (score 1):

The `-dontwarn` option isn't an option for Android Studio or the Android Gradle Plugin. It is a ProGuard option used to tell ProGuard not to warn you about potential problems.

From [the ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html):

> **-dontwarn**
>
> Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. The optional filter is a regular expression; ProGuard doesn't print warnings about classes with matching names. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly. *Only use this option if you know what you're doing!*

If you need to use this option, then it should go in your project-specific ProGuard file ([see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#enabling-gradle) if you don't know how to add your own ProGuard file).